# d3.js multiple line chart highlighting datapoints only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highlighting, bisection

I don´t quite get the hang out of the bisect function in d3.js in order to highlight the values by a vertical line.

I already got it working for one line/path but the performance is poor, at least in google chrome. Probably because my function calculates every point on the path instead of the datapoints only, which is what I actually need.

Here is the code:

```
/*create svg element*/
var svg = d3.select('.linechart')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', w)
.attr('height', h)
.attr('id', 'chart');

/*x scale*/
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
  return d[0];
})])
.range([padding, w - padding]);

/*y scale*/
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
  return d[1];
})])
.range([h - padding, padding]);

/*x axis*/
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.orient('bottom')
.ticks(20)
.tickSize(0, 0)
//.tickPadding(padding);

/*append x axis*/
svg.append('g')
.attr({
  'class': 'xaxis',
  //'transform': 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')'
  'transform': 'translate(0,' + 0 + ')'
})
.call(xAxis);

/*y axis*/
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(yScale)
.orient('left')
.tickSize(0, 0)
.tickValues([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]);

/*append y axis*/
svg.append('g')
.attr({
  'class': 'yaxis',
  'transform': 'translate(' + padding + ',0)'
})
.call(yAxis);


/*define line*/
var lines = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) {
  return xScale(d[0])
})
.y(function(d) {
  return yScale(d[1])
})
.interpolate('monotone');


/*append line*/
var path = svg.append('path')
.attr({
  'd': lines(dataset),
  'fill': 'none',
  'class': 'lineChart'
});

/*get length*/
var length = svg.select('.lineChart').node().getTotalLength();

/*animate line chart*/
svg.select('.lineChart')
.attr("stroke-dasharray", length + " " + length)
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", length)
.transition()
.ease('linear')
.delay(function(d) {
  return dataset.length * 100;
})
.duration(3000)
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

/*add points*/
var points = svg.selectAll('circle')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append('circle');

/*point attributes*/
points.attr('cy', function(d) {
  return yScale(d[1])
})
.style('opacity', 0)
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.ease('elastic')
.delay(function(d, i) {
  return i * 100;
})
.attr({
  'cx': function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  },
  'cy': function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  },
  'r': 5,
  'class': 'datapoint',
  'id': function(d, i) {
    return i;
  }
})


.style('opacity', 1);

//  LINES INDIVIDUAL
function drawIndividualLines (){

  /*define line*/
  var linesIndividual = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0])
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1])
  })
  .interpolate('monotone');

  /*append line*/
  var pathIndividual = svg.append('path')
  .attr({
    //'d': linesIndividual(datasetIndividual),
    'd': linesIndividual(datasetIndividual),
    'fill': 'none',
    'class': 'lineChartIndividual'
  });

  /*get length*/
  var lengthIndividual = svg.select('.lineChartIndividual').node().getTotalLength();

  /*animate line chart*/
  svg.select('.lineChartIndividual')
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", lengthIndividual + " " + lengthIndividual)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", lengthIndividual)
  .transition()
  .ease('linear')
  .delay(function(d) {
    return datasetIndividual.length * 100;
  })
  .duration(3000)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

  /*add points*/
  var pointsIndividual = svg.selectAll('circleIndividual')
  .data(datasetIndividual)
  .enter()
  .append('circle');

  /*point attributes*/
  pointsIndividual.attr('cy', function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1])
  })
  .style('opacity', 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .ease('elastic')
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 100;
  })
  .attr({
    'cx': function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    },
    'cy': function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    },
    'r': 5,
    'class': 'datapointIndividual',
    'id': function(d, i) {
      return i;
    }
  })


  .style('opacity', 1);
};


$(".individual").click(function() {
  drawIndividualLines();
  drawIndividualLegend();
  swapShifts();
});

var mouseG = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

mouseG.append("path") // this is the white vertical line to follow mouse
.attr("class", "mouse-line")
.style("stroke", "white")
.style("stroke-width", "1px")
.style("opacity", "0");

var linesForMouse = document.getElementsByClassName('lineChart');
var linesIndividualForMouse = document.getElementsByClassName('lineChartIndividual');

var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

mousePerLine.append("circle")
.attr("r", 7)
.style("stroke", "#A0B1AB")
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke-width", "1px")
.style("opacity", "0");

mousePerLine.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
.attr('width', w) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
.attr('height', h)
.attr('fill', 'none')
.attr('pointer-events', 'all')
.on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
  d3.select(".mouse-line")
  .style("opacity", "0");
  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
  .style("opacity", "0");
  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
  .style("opacity", "0");
})
.on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
  d3.select(".mouse-line")
  .style("opacity", "1");
  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
  .style("opacity", "1");
  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
  .style("opacity", "1");
})
.on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  d3.select(".mouse-line")
  .attr("d", function() {
    var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
    d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
    return d;
  });

  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    //console.log(w/mouse[0])
    //var xDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]),
    //bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
    //      idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

    var beginning = 0,
    end = length,
    target = null
    console.log(end);

    while (true) {
      target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
      //pos = linesForMouse[i].getPointAtLength(target);
      pos = svg.select('.lineChart').node().getPointAtLength(target);
      //console.log(pos);
      if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
        break;
      }
      if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
      else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
      else break; //position found
    }

    d3.select(this).select('text')
    .text(yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2))
    .attr("fill", "#fff");

    return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
  });
});
```

Here is a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mindcraft/vk2w7k2f/2/

So my questions are:

How do I manage to highlight the datapoints only? (Through the bisect function I don´t understand yet, I guess…)

How can I apply the same functionality to the second line (visible after clicking the "Show individual"-button in a more efficient way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can explain `d3.bisector()` for you. It will give you a huge performance improvement over searching every value between your two data points. A bisector is a form of array search for use on sorted data. But instead of searching for a particular value, you are searching for the proper index at which to insert an arbitrary value `x` in order to maintain sort order (a bisector *bisects* your array into two halves, one with values less than or equal to `x` and one with values greater than `x`). This index also gives you the closest values in your dataset to the new value (namely, `index` and `index-1`. This is how `bisector()` is really useful in your example. It will basically return the two closest values in your dataset to the location of the mouse. All you have to do is the arithmetic to find which of the two is *the closest*.

Here is an example of the process from https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/e4f5c830c264d26621b80b754219ae1b with my comments mapping to my above explanation:

```
function mousemove() {
  //convert absolute coordinates to the proper scale
  const x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
  //bisect the data
  const i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
  //get the two closest elements to the mouse
  const d0 = data[i - 1];
  const d1 = data[i];
  //check which one is actually the closest
  const d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
  //draw your lines
  focus.attr('transform', `translate(${x(d.date)}, ${y(d.close)})`);
  focus.select('line.x')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('x2', -x(d.date))
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('y2', 0);

  focus.select('line.y')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('y2', height - y(d.close));

  focus.select('text').text(formatCurrency(d.close));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation. The general concept was already clear to me but still your comments help me understand it even better. I already found that example while looking for a solution prior to asking the question here but I wasn't´t able to get it working for my current setup.

Comment: But nonetheless I tried it again but still without success.

I am using d3.js v3 but there is an example also:
https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/d66a1662fd64a08051dc473f0d1f956e

My personal problem is the data binding – or more precisely – getting the mousemove() function to work with my current data setup. I am not using a tsv-file with named tableheads but an array (two-dimensional ?) and my whole structure is different which makes it difficult to me to apply your suggested concept.

Comment: Let´s say my dataset looks like this:


`var dataset = [
  [1, (Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 50)],
  [2, (Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 50)],
  [3, (Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 50)],
  [4, (Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 50)],
  [5, (Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 50)]
];`

How do I have to define the const bisectDate? (in the example it is: const bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => d.date).left;)

Comment: It looks like you're storing your data as an array of length-2 arrays. In the case of the `d3.bisector` variable declaration, `d` would refer to each of the length-2 arrays. Assuming the "interesting" part of your data is at index 1, you would declare `const bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => d[1]).left;` If you stored your data as an array of objects({ key: value }), you could declare `d3.bisector(d => d.key)`, etc. etc.